# R left join by multiple columns resulting in NAs

Tags: r, merge, left-join

I have two data frames `alpha` and `beta`.

```
dput(alpha)

structure(list(ID = c(29503L, 29507L, 29508L, 29510L), 
               Q_ID = structure(1:4, .Label = c("q:1392763916495:441", "q:1392763916495:445", "q:1392763916495:449", "q:1392763920794:458"), 
                  class = "factor"), 
               L_Atmpt = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
               Q_Atmpt = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 1L), 
               Q_Result = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 0L), 
               Time_on_Screen = c(13839L, 185162L, 264418L, 2183464L), 
               Start_Time = structure(1:4, .Label = c("2017-10-31Ê11:51:20", "2017-10-31Ê11:54:26", "2017-10-31Ê11:59:09", "2017-10-31Ê12:35:34"), 
                  class = "factor"), 
               End_Time = structure(1:4, .Label = c("2017-10-31Ê11:51:33", "2017-10-31Ê11:57:31", "2017-10-1Ê12:03:33", "2017-10-31Ê13:11:57"), 
                  class = "factor"), 
               Duration = c(173L, 55L, 98L, 1921L)), 
               class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

```
dput(beta)
structure(list(ID = c(29503L, 29507L, 29508L, 29510L, 29515L, 30160L), 
               Q_ID = structure(1:6, .Label = c("q:1392763916495:441", "q:1392763916495:445", "q:1392763916495:449", "q:1392763920794:458", "q:1392763920794:462", "q:1392763925803:530"), 
                 class = "factor"), 
               L_Atmpt = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L), 
               Q_Atmpt = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), 
               Q_Result = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
               Time_on_Screen = c(13839L, 185162L, 264418L, 2183464L, 768470L, 885800L), 
               Start_Time = structure(c(2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L), .Label = c("2017-10-25Ê00:19:08", "2017-10-31Ê11:51:20", "2017-10-31Ê11:54:26", "2017-10-31Ê11:59:09", "2017-10-31Ê12:35:34", "2017-10-31Ê13:16:09"), 
                 class = "factor"), 
               End_Time = structure(c(2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L), .Label = c("2017-10-25Ê00:33:53", "2017-10-31Ê11:51:33", "2017-10-31Ê11:57:31", "2017-10-31Ê12:03:33", "2017-10-31Ê13:11:57", "2017-10-31Ê13:28:57"), 
                 class = "factor")), 
               class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-6L))
```

I want to merge them and get a final data frame `gamma`. The data frame `alpha` has a special column: `alpha$duration`, which I need to add or append at the end of the data frame `beta`.

`beta` has more instances than `alpha` and I want to perform left join so all the instances of `beta` are retained. This means that some of the entries of the column `gamma$duration` will be `NULL` or `NA`.

I expect, the `NULL`s or `NA`s will be those entries where the ID of `alpha` does not match with the ID of `beta`. However, for my original data (which has more than 10K rows and around 20 or so variables), I get something like below:

```
ID    Q_ID               L_Atmpt Q_Atmpt Q_Result Time_on_Screen Start_Time End_Time        Duration
29503 q:1392763916495:441   0   0   1   13839   2017-10-31Ê11:51:20 2017-10-31Ê11:51:33 NA  
29507 q:1392763916495:445   0   1   1   185162  2017-10-31Ê11:54:26 2017-10-31Ê11:57:31 NA  
29508 q:1392763916495:449   0   0   1   264418  2017-10-31Ê11:59:09 2017-10-31Ê12:03:33 NA  
29510 q:1392763920794:458   0   1   0   2183464 2017-10-31Ê12:35:34 2017-10-31Ê13:11:57 NA  
29515 q:1392763920794:462   0   0   0   768470  2017-10-31Ê13:16:09 2017-10-31Ê13:28:57 NA  
30160 q:1392763925803:530   1   0   0   885800  2017-10-25Ê00:19:08 2017-10-25Ê00:33:53 NA
```

Unfortunately, the toy example that I shared is not replicating/capturing my problem. I understand it could be challenging to imagine why I am getting `NA` in my original problem. But any thoughts or advice on this would be highly appreciated.

For reference, I am sharing the different scripts that I have used, they all have rendered the same output:

```
library(plyr)
gamma = join(beta, alpha, type = "left")

library(dplyr)
gamma = left_join(beta, alpha)

library(sqldf)
gamma = sqldf('SELECT beta.*, alpha.duration
               FROM beta LEFT JOIN alpha
               on beta.ID == alpha.ID AND
               beta.Q_ID == alpha.Q_ID AND
               beta.L_Atmpt == alpha.L_Atmpt AND
               beta.Q_Atmpt == alpha.Q_Atmpt AND
               beta.Start_Time == alpha.Start_Time')
```

I would like to mention that the column `alpha$duration` in my original data frame was created after some pre-processing steps such as:

```
#Step 1: Ordering the data by ID and Start_Time
beta = beta[with(beta, order(ID, Q_ID, Q_Atmpt, Start_Time)), ]

#Step 2: End_Time lagging
library(Hmisc)
# to calculate the time difference we lag the End_Time
beta$End_Time_forward = Lag(beta$End_Time, +1)
# for comparisons, we also lag the IDs
beta$ID_forward = Lag(beta$ID, +1)

#Step 3: Now calculate the required time differences
library(sqldf)
alpha = sqldf('SELECT beta.*, 
                (Start_Time - End_Time_forward), 
                (End_Time - End_Time_forward)
              FROM beta
              WHERE ID_forward == ID')

#Step 4: Columns renaming
names(alpha)[names(alpha) == "(Start_Time - End_Time_forward)"] = "duration"
names(alpha)[names(alpha) == "(End_Time - End_Time_forward)"] = "end_duration"

#Step 5:Few instances have negative duration, so replace the gap between 
# (last end time and current start time) with the (last end time and current 
# end time) difference
alpha =  alpha %>%
  mutate(duration = if_else(duration < 0, end_duration, duration))

#Step 6: Convert the remaining negatives with NAs
alpha$duration[alpha$duration < 0] <- NA

#Step 7: Now replace those NAs by using the imputeTS function
library(imputeTS)
alpha$duration = na_locf(alpha$duration, option = 'locf', 
                         na_remaining = 'rev', maxgap = Inf)
```

I suspect, the last two steps where I have manipulated the `gamma$duration` variable might have something to do with such unexpected results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not been able to determine the actual cause of this issue, however, I have found a work-around this problem:

```
beta$duration = as.integer(0)

test2 = merge(x = beta, y = alpha, 
by = c("ID", "Q_ID", "L_Atmpt", "Q_Atmpt", "Q_Result", "Time_on_Screen", "Start_Time", "End_Time"),
all.x = TRUE)
```

Through this, I can access/retain the `duration` column of the data frame `alpha` and then use it as I want to.